# Getting String between two Strings with regular Expressions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

I have a long String:

```
1;#Subject:SW|&#13;&#10;vti_parserversion:SR|14.0.0.4762&#13;&#10;vti_folderitemcount:IR|0&#13;&#10;_Category:SW|&#13;&#10;vti_author:SR|SHAREPOINT\\system&#13;&#10;_dlc_DocIdItemGuid:SW|8435986b-4ff2-4e03-9879-d15568d88f0b&#13;&#10;vti_approvallevel:SR|&#13;&#10;vti_categories:VW|&#13;&#10;vti_foldersubfolderitemcount:IR|0&#13;&#10;vti_modifiedby:SR|SHAREPOINT\\system&#13;&#10;vti_assignedto:SR|&#13;&#10;Keywords:SW|&#13;&#10;_Status:SW|&#13;&#10;vti_cachedcustomprops:VX|vti_approvallevel vti_categories Subject vti_assignedto Keywords _Status vti_title _Author _Category _dlc_DocId _Comments _dlc_DocIdUrl _dlc_DocIdItemGuid&#13;&#10;ContentTypeId:SW|0x01010013CD7B577B3AC84B8467BC0F2B82B30D&#13;&#10;_dlc_DocId:SW|5VQNHKQHD5Z4-9-1&#13;&#10;vti_cachedtitle:SR|SharePoint 2010 Deployment Guide&#13;&#10;vti_title:SR|SharePoint 2010 Deployment Guide&#13;&#10;_Author:SW|&#13;&#10;_dlc_DocIdUrl:SW|http://blub.com/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=5VQNHKQHD5Z4-9-2, 5VQNHKQHD5Z4-9-1&#13;&#10;_Comments:SW|&#13;&#10;
```

And I want to parse the DocIdUrl (the String between "_dlc_DocIdUrl:SW|" and ",") , I am using RegexKitLite with: `String stringByMatching:regExP`

This is my first RegExpression: `NSString* regExp = @"(?=\_dlc_DocIdUrl:SW|)(.*?)(?=\,)";`

But it gives me: _dlc_DocIdUrl:SW|http://blub.com/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=5VQNHKQHD5Z4-9-2

I only want the URL, how can i solve that?

I am confused!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex solving your problem:

```
_dlc_DocIdUrl:SW\|(?<value>[^,]*),+
```

You will find the requested URL in the group named "value"

Comment: With this Iam getting null?!
Maybe Iam wrong with RegexKitLite?!
Iam working with: stringByMatching
How do I work with groups when stringByMatching gives me an NSString back?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=_dlc_DocIdUrl:SW\|)[^,]*(?=,)
```

this give you what you need directly, without grouping.

Comment: This is what Iam getting now:
2;#vti_parserversion:SR|14.0.0.4762
vti_modifiedby:SR|DOMAIN\\myNAME
vti_folderitemcount:IR|0
vti_foldersubfolderitemcount:IR|0
ContentTypeId:SW|0x01010013CD7B577B3AC84B8467BC0F2B82B30D
_dlc_DocId:SW|5VQNHKQHD5Z4-9-2
vti_author:SR|DOMAIN\\Name
_dlc_DocIdItemGuid:SW|33047fc7-f6e9-40ce-ab0a-415cc1d666c3
_dlc_DocIdUrl:SW|http://InternetADRESS.com/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=5VQNHKQHD5Z4-9-2

How do I work with groups?
stringByMatching gives me a string back...